# JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been staring at this code for hours trying to validate and i can't seem to find the error. It's a basic program using arrays to store and display phone numbers with letters to phone numbers with numbers. Its probably something simple i'm missing but i need new eyes, any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
//Phone number translator

var Letters = new Array();
Letters[0] = "ABC";
Letters[1] = "DEF";
Letters[2] = "GHI";
Letters[3] = "JKL";
Letters[4] = "MNO";
Letters[5] = "PQRS";
Letters[6] = "TUV";
Letters[7] = "WXYZ";

var Numbers = new Array();
Numbers[0] = "2";
Numbers[1] = "3";
Numbers[2] = "4";
Numbers[3] = "5";
Numbers[4] = "6";
Numbers[5] = "7";
Numbers[6] = "8";
Numbers[7] = "9";

// Main routine

var userPhone = prompt("Enter a phone number in the format 999-XXX-XXXX");
alert("userPhone = " + userPhone);



var partsPhone = userPhone.split("-",3);

alert("partsPhone[0] = " + partsPhone[0] + "\npartsPhone[1] = " +     partsPhone[1] + "\npartsPhone[2] = " + partsPhone[2]);

//partsPhone[0] = areacode
//partsPhone[1] = prefix 
//partsPhone[2] = extension 

var areacode = partsPhone[0];

var prefix = translate(partsPhone[1],3);

var sPrefix = prefix.join("");

var extension = translate(partsPhone[2],4);

var sExtensition = extension.join("");

alert("The numeric version of the phone number is \n" + "                " + areacode + "-" + sPrefix + "-" + sExtension);




function translate(str, numChars)
{
var outerControl = 0;
var innerControl = 0;
 var done = false;

var trString = new Array();


for(outerControl = 0; outerControl < numChars; outerControl++)
{
  done = false;
  for(innerControl = 0; (innerControl < Letters.length) && !done; innerControl++)
  {
   if (str[outerControl] == Letters[innerControl].charAt(0) ||
       str[outerControl] == Letters[innerControl].charAt(1) ||
       str[outerControl] == Letters[innerControl].charAt(2))
    {
        trString[outerControl] = Numbers[innerControl];
        done = true;

    }
    else
    {
       if (Letters[innerControl].length > 3)
       {
          if (str[outerControl] == Letters[innerControl].charAt(3))
          {
          trString[outerControl] = Numbers[innerControl];
          done = true;
        }
      }
     }
   }
}
return trString;
}
```

Comment: What **is** the error you're getting..?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?  What is it doing?  What error are you getting?

Comment: @NickZuber I can't get it to run at all, it just shows up with my HTML container.

Comment: If you open the console (F12), it will tell you what syntax errors you have, and what line they are on, and there are errors.

Comment: Did you wrap it in <script .... tags?

Comment: Don't debug with `alert()` use the console instead. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: *it just shows up with my HTML container* Are you wrapping your JavaScript in `<script>` tags?

Comment: @nurdyguy yes I did wrap it in script tags

Comment: Try opening up the Developer Console (F12 if in chrome) and see what the errors are yourself. You can't just copy and paste your program into a question and expect us to go on a scavenger hunt for for a typographical error.

Comment: @KylieMarino  Sorry, I know that was a silly question.  I only asked because you said "it just shows up with my HTML container".

Comment: Fixed my syntax error, and the beginning is running but now more specifically it isn't displaying (translating) the letters as numbers

Comment: @nurdyguy No worries! Everything is a worth a shot!

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error

```
 str[outerControl == Letters[innerControl].charAt(1)
```

should be

```
 str[outerControl] == Letters[innerControl].charAt(1)
```

and, put the AND (&&) or OR (||) operators in your if statement

It seems you are keeping on typo.

now, change sExtensition to sExtension

Comment: and operators in the statement